# error when creating configuration and can't resolve setClassForTemplateLoading() and getTemplate()

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, configuration, pom.xml, freemarker

I am a newbie in IntelliJ IDEA and trying freemarker and maven.
i just installed that software and tried a freemarker project and it shows to override method for configuration object creation. if i do that i can't use setClassForTemplateLoading(). it shows can't resolve this one. and also the getTemplate().

```
public class HelloWorldFreemarkerStyle {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();//shows error, insisting to use override method
    cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(HelloWorldFreemarkerStyle.class, "/");//can't resolve

    try {
        Template helloTemplate = cfg.getTemplate("hello.ftl");// can't resolve
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        Map<String, Object> helloMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        helloMap.put("name", "Vicky");
        helloTemplate.process(helloMap, writer);
        System.out.println(writer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

freemarker dependencies:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
      <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.20</version>
</dependency>
```

hello.ftl:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello ${name}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the list of imports in your `HelloWorldFreemarkerStyle` file please? It's possible an incorrect class has been imported.

Comment: package com.mongodb;

    import freemarker.template.Template;

    import javax.security.auth.login.Configuration;
    import java.io.StringWriter;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

Comment: thank you mam, import freemarker.template.Configuration; this import class library was not there, now the errors are rectified. thanks a lot mam...

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use 2.3.20 when there's 2.3.23... it gives better error messages for example, which is to spare *your* time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're importing

```
import freemarker.template.Configuration;
```

at the top of your file, not

```
import javax.security.auth.login.Configuration;
```